How to hide the editor overlay text which displays the active solution name in a light red box
JetBrains Rider displays the name of the active solution in a very annoying overlay, please see the screenshot.
How can we remove it?

I tried to find a solutions since hours:

I have disabled all extensions and the overlay is still displayed
I have searched in the settings for: "Overlay", "Project", "Solution", "Show", "Hide", …

Thanks a lot for any hint!,
kind regards,
Thomas

After hours, I have found the issue:
I had never set an Editor background, but IntelliJ Rider got one / added one.
After I had clicked on "Clear and Close", the annoyance was gone :-):

